# How to extract some specific content from the html response

Tags: jquery

I wrote a listener for a button as shown below

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnclick", function() {

var htmlString = $("div#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-details").eq(0).html(); 

console.log(htmlString);

});
```

The result of above htmlString is

```
<h6 class="tdHeading">Regular, 50 Ml 1</h6>
<i id="topping-close"></i><img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
<section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a></section>
<section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>

<h6 class="tdHeading">Regular, 50 Ml 2</h6>
<i id="topping-close"></i><img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
<section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a></section>
<section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>

<h6 class="tdHeading">Regular, 50 Ml 3</h6>
<i id="topping-close"></i><img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
<section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a></section>
<section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
```

Right now i got three rows of data mentioned above

My requirement is that on click of a button , i need to add one more row of the whole thing (**incrementing  the number under h6**)
so taht it look like this , and append it to the existing  htmlString

```
<h6 class="tdHeading">Regular, 50 Ml 4</h6>
<i id="topping-close"></i><img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
<section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a></section>
<section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
```

I am able to get the count of the last h6 using this way , but couldn't able to proceed on how to add this new content back to the existing htmlString

```
var n = $("div#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-details h6").length ;

<h6 class="tdHeading">Regular, 50 Ml 4</h6>
<i id="topping-close"></i><img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
<section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a></section>
<section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
```

Could anybody please help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Div append should do it.

```
var n = $("div#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-details h6").length ;
var text1 = $('.secclass a')[0].text;
var text2 = $('.secclass a')[1].text;
$("div#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-details h6").parent().append('<h6 class="tdHeading">Regular, 50 Ml '+n+'</h6>    <i id="topping-close"></i><img src="images/arrow-topping.png">    <section class="secclass"><a href="#">+text1 +</a></section>    <section class="secclass"><a href="#">+text2 +</a></section>')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , This two values Honey with Carmel  10 ML and Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML may vary for different components , so i need to extartc these .

Comment: Thank you very much , but this new section is being added to all the previous ones , i just want to append it to the end of the exisiting thing (at the end ).

Comment: you have saved my day . and is it possible to extract the text1  and text2 values dynamically ??

Comment: Thank you very much , The secclass  can have n number of elements means this is not fixed .

Comment: You can't. There is no separator between each section so all .secclass would be selected. It could be done if you would start with one section and then generate many in one go, or you would have separator between each section to select only one or 'parent' section something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/AKLvv/3/